# Rotating a unity configurable joint to match another game object (copycat)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, gameobject

I'm trying to drive a configurable joint to the same rotation as another game object. Basically I'm trying to get one marionette to shadow another.

Im using the following code:

```
 public GameObject master;
 public GameObject slave;

 void Update (){
     ConfigurableJoint cj = slave.transform.GetComponent(typeof(ConfigurableJoint)) as ConfigurableJoint;
     cj.targetRotation = master.transform.rotation;
 }
```

However, I don't get any rotation out of the slave. Can anyone explain what I should be doing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting the right joint ? Is cj null ?

Maybe try this line instead :

```
ConfigurableJoint cj = slave.GetComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
```

Comment: Hi, so I can see that is changing the target rotation now. But the joint is still not moving. Should I be applying power somehow?

Comment: @ChrisHeadleand. Have you configured the salve joint properly ?  Check the status of  Angular XMotion ,
,Angular YMotion 
,Angular ZMotion

Comment: Also you should make sure that the joint has a rotation drive set up correctly. This is the force that rotates the joint. Perhaps you should take it from the master joint.

Comment: Sorry can you explain how to use rotation drive? I think this must be the bit I am missing

Comment: Check the setting on AngularDriveX and AngularDriveYZ. Also could you please provide a screenshot of the joint in question ?

Comment: Try setting the Mode on the Angular drives to something else than disabled. I'm still not sure what you are trying to do , so you might have to experiment. But I'm pretty sure that that is your problem. That or the joints are still broken in Unity5.

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with physics you can't apply rotation to a Rigid Body. What you can do is copy and paste the local transform to another non-static game object in relationship with its perent that does not contain a Rigid Body.

So basically the configurable joint has so so many options and parameters to set it up to your need that you need to take a course 2hrs course. There is no space here for a simple answer to set it up. I recommend this free old course because is the only one that at the moment explains in deep: This is more a general answer but works. There is an old tutorial in Unity3 that explains the setup:

https://archive.org/details/3dbuzz-archive/unity-fundamentals-part-04/020-physics/013-13-configurable-joint.mp4